What is the meaning of the biblical term "divine nature", and what does it tell us about the biblical use of the title "God"?
In connection with the term "God", mainstream Christology often uses the term “nature of God” or “divine nature”, especially when it comes to describing the triune God’s essence or substance, as it is found in Christ who is said to be the "God-man" in the hypostatic union, having both a fully human and a fully divine nature. Considering myself a human, I think to understand what is meant by "human" nature, as being part of the human species/lifeform.
The term “divine nature” however seems quite abstract, and is found only once in the Bible, in 2 Peter 1:4

by which have been given to us exceedingly great and precious
promises, that through these you may be partakers of the divine
nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through
lust.

Re-born Christians have the “great and precious promise” of being “partakers of the divine nature”. The same Christians „shall be like Him (God)“ according to the Bible (1. John 3:2).
One could conclude from this that Christians who become "partakers of the divine nature", fully inherit the "divine nature" when they go to heaven, and thus become fully God, if the term "God" is to be understood as a lifeform. On this point, I think most mainstream Christians would agree, that this is not the case - heavenly resurrected Christians don't become the "God" lifeform, but the "spirit" lifeform, as they receive a spiritual body.

It is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. There is a
natural body, and there is a spiritual body.
As was the man of dust, so also are those who are made of dust; and as
is the heavenly Man, so also are those who are heavenly. And as we
have borne the image of the man of dust, we shall also bear the image
of the heavenly Man. (1. Corinthians 15:44,48-49)

Some Trinitarian Bible commentators agree:

the Divine nature may be understood of the glory and immortality of
the other life, wherein we shall be conformed to God, and whereof by
the promises we are made partakers. - Matthew Poole's commentary


that by these you might be partakers of the divine nature; not
essentially, or of the essence of God, so as to be deified, this is
impossible, for the nature, perfections, and glory of God, are
incommunicable to creatures; nor, hypostatically and personally, so as
the human nature of Christ, in union with the Son of God, is a
partaker of the divine nature in him; but by way of resemblance and
likeness, the new man or principle of grace, being formed in the heart
in regeneration, after the image of God, and bearing a likeness to the
image of his Son, and this is styled, Christ formed in the heart, into
which image and likeness the saints are more and more changed, from
glory to glory, through the application of the Gospel, and the
promises of it, by which they have such sights of Christ as do
transform them, and assimilate them to him; and which resemblance will
be perfected hereafter, when they shall be entirely like him, and see
him as he is - Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible

“God is a spirit” (John 4:24)
A spirit is a (for humans) invisible supernatural lifeform.
Thayer's Greek Lexicon describes the lifeform as:


"a spirit, i. e. a simple essence, devoid of all or at least all grosser matter, and possessed of the power of knowing, desiring,
deciding, and acting";


Hence the question: the only time the Bible speaks of the "divine nature" it appears that from a biblical standpoint it means the lifeform of "incorruptible spiritual bodies".
What other meaning can be drawn of the unique term "divine nature" from a biblical perspective? What is the biblical exegesis behind this term often used to describe God's essence?
That the Almighty God is a unique person/being is out of the question, but is God a unique type of lifeform as appears to be the understanding and intermittent use of the term by people believing in the homoousion? If so, what is the biblical basis for this claim?
If not, what does the biblical term "God" really mean?

The term 'lifeform' has no real meaning within this type of discussion. Merriam Webster : the body form that characterizes a kind of organism. As one of the answers underlines it is pointless to attempt to understand this area of theology if one has not been born again and received the Person of the Holy Spirit. There will be no sensation of spirit with which to understand the divine spirit.

Feel free to replace "lifeform" with "living essence/being".  God is a Spirit, and according to Thayer's Greek Lexicon "a simple essence, devoid of all or at least all grosser matter, and possessed of the power of knowing, desiring, deciding, and acting". So are Angels, and so are those resurrected in heaven with an incorruptible spiritual body - said to become "just like [God]" (1 John 3:2)

'Essence' and 'being' are just forms of the word 'to be' which does not convey anything at all. A stone can 'be'. Jesus said Pneuma ho Theos 'Spirit the Deity'. 'Spirit' is the nature of Deity. But one needs the Holy Spirit, dwelling within, to appreciate what his words mean.

I think Trinitarians and Jehovah Witnesses alike agree, that the term "God" refers to the unique being who is beyond our universe and who created our universe out of nothing.  Trinitarians use the term "nature of God" / "divine nature" 1) to understand properties of this being, 2) to understand the nature of Jesus, and 3) to understand how God's children become "like God" (1 John 3:2).
We understand God within our limited capacity in our status as a created being in the image of God, which I'm sure Jehovah Witnesses also agree.  Accordingly, the language about God that the Bible uses is necessarily limited and is not meant to exhaust the nature of God.  In philosophical terms, it is simply impossible to DEFINE God, or to put this unique Being under a genus.  So when the Bible says "God is spirit" (John 4:24, ESV), the word "spirit" is NOT a genus, but how we understand God in contrast with our own nature (a body animated with God-created soul) which we can understand better.
Secondly, the Bible is a text about salvation, not a formal philosophical text about the nature of God, the topic discussed within the discipline of Philosophy of Religion or within Christian theology.

So John 4:24 exhorts us to worship God "in spirit and truth" meaning that since God created our soul (which is also spirit), we have the capacity to commune with God spirit to spirit.  BUT it does NOT mean we can bring down God's spirit nature to our level.  The context is how we should worship God.  John is not defining God to a particular definition of "spirit"; he only says that God's nature is spiritual, and that worship in the New Testament era can be direct human soul to God, no longer need to be mediated by sacrifice in the temple or through some other physical ritual.

Similarly, when 2 Peter 1:4 says "partakers of the divine nature", the context is salvation, not philosophy of religion.  Trinitarians DO NOT equate this "divine nature" with the language of the creed, which is philosophical.  "partakers" here means God has given us His Holy Spirit (who has this same "divine nature") to dwell within us, someone who is working to sanctify us from sinful nature that has "sinful desire".  The Holy Spirit produces within us the spiritual fruits that Gal 5:22 talks about.

Lastly, when 1 Cor 15:44 talks about "spiritual body", it refers to our glorified body which God gives us when we are resurrected.  This verse simply means that our glorified body will be more like God, but it is STILL bodily.  Paul contrast this with our current state of body which he terms "natural body" (ESV).  Again, it is VERY important not to equate the meaning of "spirit" here with the meaning of God's spiritual nature.  Like the other 2 verses, this verse does NOT attempt to define God's divine nature / spiritual nature, but for Paul to communicate to us how God will grant us more of his nature to us, more than what we already possess when we were born (i.e. the "image of God").  Even in "spiritual body", we still cannot EVER be completely like God; see this answer which includes how Cyril of Alexandria processed Scripture to identify 4 meanings of "sonship" and how we only receive 2 of them.


Conclusion: When Trinitarians try to understand God's nature philosophically in the Nicene creed by using the term homoousion we DO NOT attempt to define God exhaustively or by putting God under the genus of "divine nature" and labeling that genus "homoousion".  The purpose was to elucidate more precisely the relation of God to Jesus and to the Holy Spirit.  We do NOT simply use the term "divine nature" as Peter used it in 2 Peter 1:4, but we use a range of verses (primarily John 1:1) to substantiate indirectly what we mean by "homoousion", understood by Trinitarians as a shared nature between the 3 Trinitarian "persons".  As I explained above, Biblical verses have salvation as their primary function, not to be woodenly used in philosophical reflection about God.
I hope I managed to answer your question.  Please comments if there are issues I don't address here.

Thanks for your answer. I like the distinction being made between religious philosophy and the scriptures. I personally think that both don’t really go well together as is explicitly said in Colossians 2:8 and 1 Corinthians 1:19-25. Philosophy is the “love of (human) wisdom”. Whereas the philosophical notion of “divine nature” may have a scriptural touch, I have found that the philosophy is often regarded as superior to scripture, forcing scripture to be made compliant with the philosophy. Getting to know the only true God as well as Jesus means everlasting life/salvation (John 17:3)

@JsWitness Yes, the distinction is important.  Even from the 2nd century there have been 2 camps evaluating the value of philosophy, Tertullian vs. Justin Martyr.  Trinitarian Western Christianity has taken the Justin Martyr route.  But I think JW and us can agree that regardless of Trinitarian speculation of God, the most important is the "being to being" worship, communication, faith, and dependence between us and Jesus/God, resulting in everlasting life.  True Christian philosophy depends on Scripture.  You and I may disagree, but good Trinitarians don't put our concepts above Scripture.

I couldn’t agree more - you have my upvote.

This is not a question to disparage, but it does cause despair amongst those who know experientially that they are already born from above, "partakers of the divine nature", then seeing one who is not, trying to explain their understanding of the divine nature of God.
Immediately, it needs to be said that all Jehovah's Witnesses who do not partake of the emblems at their annual Memorial are publicly declaring that they have not been re-born, and that they do not partake of the divine nature. Only if the O.P. partakes of the bread and wine at that event, has a public testimony been given that they consider themselves anointed of 'holy spirit' and will be with Christ in heaven. As the belief is that only 144,000 humans from the time of Christ till his still future return can make that claim, it is reasonable to assume that the OP is not part of that group who know themselves to be born again, partakers of the divine nature.
Now, it is good that a question has been asked, seeking an explanation about what mainstream trinitarian theology means by the biblical term "God" in relation to his divine nature. Explanation has been given as to why this confuses the OP, so my task is to offer the trinitarian explanation in light of that confusion.
First, human nature is not equal to the divine nature. Nor can the greatest human intellect work that out (Luke 10:21). The nature of God is the deepest subject any person can ever consider, and God is not given to revealing all that he is, to satisfy human curiosity. However, he has chosen to reveal certain things about his nature, written of in the Bible, and supremely demonstrated in the person of Jesus Christ who alone can reveal the Father (John 14:6-7). Equally, only the Father can draw people to come to Christ (John 6:44 & 65). This means that God and Christ take the initiative in revealing the nature of deity to those whom they choose. An example of this is what Jesus said to Peter when asking who he thought he was. A revealing of just who Jesus is was given to him by the Father - Matthew 16:15-17. Do you see what you are up against? Do you see that you could be searching in all the wrong places, seeking an intellectual explanation that will satisfy you? You will never get that. The only starting-point for sorting this out is to come to the risen Christ in faith and to confess him alone, then the Holy Spirit will do that work of revealing just who he, and the Father are. He won't go on about himself, for his role is to uplift Christ, but without the Holy Spirit, nobody can understand the divine nature of God, in Christ.
There is a cut-to-the-chase answer that avoids all superfluous ideas that only cause confusion. It is in the book I now quote from:

"In the nature of what Deity is, that nature is possessed by a Person,
who is named Jesus Christ. He shares that nature with his Father. In
relationship, regarding person, his Father is greater than he is. But
in the matter of nature, eternal nature, his nature is equal to that
of the Father and he is perfectly one with the Father. As well as
this, Jesus Christ, born of woman, also possesses human nature.
The Divine relationship is within one Spirit, the Divine Person who is
the Holy Spirit. All that passes between the Father and the Son, and
between the son and the Father, does so in one Spirit. That Spirit is
a divine Person sharing the same divine nature as the Father and the
Son.
Fulness is one of the attributes of Deity. And since that attribute is
shared, then it follows that there must be, and there indeed is, a
perfection of unity within Deity. For each shares the attribute of
fulness. Everything, absolutely everything, is filled by Deity. By all
that is Deity. Thus there is absolutely a shared perfection of unity.
In all things. This is sheer logic.
Only once was that perfect bond within Deity ever broken... "My God,
my God, why hast thou forsaken me?" This appalling breach within
everlasting Deity was caused by the bearing of sin. And by the
resolving of the matter of sin, by means of death. This, the awful
rift in the most perfect of relationships, was accepted and agreed
upon by Deity in unanimous counsel, before the earth was created, for
it was foreseen by the wisdom of Deity that it would be necessary. And
yet Deity still created humanity. What revelation is this : it is
wonderful!" The Everlasting Gospel p.43-44, Nigel Johnstone,
Belmont, 2017

Now, that quote may be dismissed as gobbledegook by those who do not agree with the Trinity doctrine. Well, it was never going to be easy to explain anything about the divine nature of God to anyone not yet re-born, not yet knowing what it is to partake of the divine nature. But trinitarians do try to explain matters when asked to give reasons for their hope. Yet without the Holy Spirit giving revelation, that will avail nothing. And if one just thinks of 'holy spirit' as an 'it', and thinks Jesus had a starting point in time, only the grace of God revealing the truth of God will overcome. The Bible reveals such matters, as the Spirit leads.

In Luke 10:21 Jesus praises his Father that He has hidden the holy insight from Intellectuals, yet the Trinity dogma as we know it today was concocted over centuries only by Intellectuals (from a human standpoint) - https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/trinity/trinity-history.html#:~:text=Many%2520thinkers%2520influential%2520in%2520the,1988%252C%2520856%E2%80%93869). Isn’t that ironic- if the Trinity is true, God has chosen the wise and intellectuals of the world to make it known - He has in fact resorted to human philosophy to make it understandable. He has gone against His own word.

@JsWitness There are a great many trinitarians who hold their beliefs from scripture alone without ever delving into what the "intellectuals" have written.  Isn't that interesting?

I have yet to meet a Trinitarian that doesn’t use non-biblical language such as “God the Son”, “God the HS”, “hypostatic union”, “homoousion”. I find it very unlikely that they have come up with such words on their own without reading Church creeds, Theologians, or referring to Church Fathers that have convinced them of these ideas. Furthermore, even if what you say is true, the Trinity dogma is arguably at best non-explicitly taught in the Bible, and still accepted by the vast majority of Christians… but Jesus said that true Christianity would always be a minority view (Matthew 7:14, 21)

@JsWitness Yes, many non-professional-theologian Christians would just parrot those terminologies, but Trinitarian professors of theology can explain how various Trinitarian conceptions about God (it's not just parroting the creedal language !) are derived from Scripture. If you really want to know, you can read this 2022 book  The Trinity: On the Nature and Mystery of the One God or listen to the author being interviewed about it here.

@Anne "Only once was that perfect bond within Deity ever broken" This doesn't sound like an orthodox Trinitarian Chalcedonian explanation, which is understandable since your quote doesn't factor the dual nature of Christ into the possible meaning of why Jesus uttered that cry.  For an alternative explanation, read this article: Was the Trinity Torn Apart at the Cross?

@GratefulDisciple  Thanks for the link, but it's really the author I quoted who would need to respond. I shall get back to you on this.

@Anne  The Person cried out, forsaken. The link speaks of 'God, the Son, suffering'. If the suffering was only a human matter then only one (other) human could benefit from that sacrifice. What passed in the darkness, which none other can fathom, was within Deity. I choose only to comment to yourself, Anne. I shall not debate it further. Regards.

@GratefulDisciple  I've read the link and would say that the author I quoted was not saying "the Trinity was torn apart". Nor was he suggesting "a binity-plus-one".

@Anne You may have the benefit of reading the whole work while I'm just remarking 2 clear language within the quote suggesting a break / breach within the Trinity: "Only once was that perfect bond within Deity ever broken" (implying the Trinity is in time) and "appalling breach within everlasting Deity" (implying some kind of disunity).  The 3rd language "awful rift in the most perfect of relationships" would be less problematic if attributed to Jesus's consciousness IN his human nature, but given the previous 2 instances attributed to the immanent Trinity the reader can be misled.

@NigelJ We can have a friendly discussion instead of a debate in a chatroom I just created here. Feedback to "If the suffering was only a human matter then ...": if we conceive that God the Son suffers in the flesh of Jesus who is the single lamb God offers for us to expiate all our sins, this single Divine Man CAN benefits many.   So I think you are presenting a false dilemma.  Plus, no break/breach within the Godhead needs to be postulated as in His divine nature God continually loves Jesus within the immanent Trinity.

@NigelJ As for the separation, the benefit of conceiving that God the Son suffers in His human nature is this: Jesus, who not only satisfies justice by paying for our sins with his life (that worth a lot more than one single person, since he is a divine), out of compassion to us he ALSO suffers the consequences of ALL our sins which INCLUDES feeling subjective separation from God in his human nature, to identify with our own estrangement from God whenever we sin. Thus in enduring our sin's temporal consequences, we can be thankful that Jesus fully understands us and gives us strength.

Divine nature refers to the fact that we were created by God and as He is Our Father, we have part of Him in us.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We look for well researched answers that back up claims or views posted in response to questions. Please take our Tour to find out how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

P.S. I did not down-vote your answer.
